# How to read the assembly code of this piece of Rust code?

Tags: assembly, rust, x86-64, reverse-engineering

I am trying to read a piece of Rust assembly code, but actually, it's harder to read than the ASM code generated by the C/C++ compiler. So, how to analyze the ASM code of the below piece of Rust code?

```
fn main() { 
    let closure = |x| println!("{}", x);
    let x: fn(x: i32) -> () = closure; 
    println!("{}", x as i32);
}
```

The corresponding assembly code like below with some comments (I only pasted the main part, for full version please use this Permalink: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=e7ba4844f1ce6e881912dc074152988d):

```
playground::main: # @playground::main
# %bb.0:
    subq    $72, %rsp
    leaq    core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once(%rip), %rax
    movl    %eax, 4(%rsp)
    leaq    4(%rsp), %rax
    movq    %rax, 8(%rsp)
    movq    core::fmt::num::imp::<impl core::fmt::Display for i32>::fmt@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, 16(%rsp)
    leaq    .L__unnamed_2(%rip), %rax  # the contents of rdx come from .L__unnamed_2(%rip), how to evaluate this part?
    movq    %rax, 24(%rsp)  # the contents of rdi come from rax.
    movq    $2, 32(%rsp)
    movq    $0, 40(%rsp)
    leaq    8(%rsp), %rax
    movq    %rax, 56(%rsp)
    movq    $1, 64(%rsp)
    leaq    24(%rsp), %rdi  # rdi should be the register holding the value passed to println!.
    callq   *std::io::stdio::_print@GOTPCREL(%rip)
    addq    $72, %rsp
    retq
                                        # -- End function

main:                                   # @main
# %bb.0:
    subq    $8, %rsp
    movq    %rsi, %rcx
    movslq  %edi, %rdx
    leaq    playground::main(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, (%rsp)
    leaq    .L__unnamed_1(%rip), %rsi
    movq    %rsp, %rdi
    callq   *std::rt::lang_start_internal@GOTPCREL(%rip)
                                        # kill: def $eax killed $eax killed $rax
    popq    %rcx
    retq
                                        # -- End function

.L__unnamed_1:
    .quad   core::ptr::drop_in_place<std::rt::lang_start<()>::{{closure}}>
    .quad   8                               # 0x8
    .quad   8                               # 0x8
    .quad   std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}
    .quad   std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}
    .quad   core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once{{vtable.shim}}

.L__unnamed_3:

.L__unnamed_4:
    .byte   10

.L__unnamed_2:
    .quad   .L__unnamed_3
    .zero   8
    .quad   .L__unnamed_4
    .asciz  "\001\000\000\000\000\000\000"
```

And, I am trying to find how the Rust compiler treats the function pointer of closure versus normal function. So, here I tried to use a closure as an example but seems I cannot find any valid assembly code that corresponds to the use of the variable "x".

Comment: Are you sure the top of playground::main is copy-pasted correctly?  `leaq    core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once(%rip), %rax` / `movl    %eax, 4(%rsp)` ??   Is there some reason the compiler would LEA a 64-bit address and then only store the low 32 bits of it to a local?  Hmm, https://godbolt.org/z/z8j8razx7 confirms that code-gen.  Looks very weird.  At least a missed optimization; could have used 32-bit operand-size in LEA if truncating the pointer somehow makes sense.  Or is that your doing with the `as i32`?

Comment: Yes, tested. If you change the `as i32` to `as i64`, the `movl %eax, 4(%rsp)` will be changed to `movq %rax, (%rsp)`.

Comment: Also note: `# the contents of rdi come from rax.` isn't right, for the normal meaning of "contents of register = its value".  RDI when `_print` is called *points at* this struct which starts with the pointer to `.L__unnamed_2` stored from RAX to `24(%rsp)`.  Note that it's an LEA not a MOV reload, so it's not copying this RAX into later RDI.  (Perhaps you meant "contents of memory pointed-to by RDI", not "contents of RDI"?)

Comment: So what is this code actually doing, for the benefit of Rust newbies like myself?  It's printing (the address of?) a closure, converted to an i32?  That seems consistent with the asm, and I guess the compiler chooses not to optimize away contents of the closure object itself, even though your code truncates the pointer so there's no way `_print` could actually deref it anymore.

Comment: @PeterCordes Closures in Rust can be [coerced to function pointers](/a/52703106/3650362) if they don't capture anything, and this is what's happening here. That's why it's not taking an address of the closure object itself, but of its implementation (`core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once`). Almost all of `main` is formatting noise, as transistor's answer also points out.

Comment: YHSPY, a technique you might find useful for analyzing assembly code without all the `println!` stuff is to write a function that takes a function pointer and call it with the value: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/vvrca6Gq5). Since a function pointer can do anything, this will stop LLVM from optimizing the whole function away but doesn't add a bunch of formatting code mixed in with the rest of the function. (Unless the formatting code is the point of your question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no actual call to the closure, so no invocation code has been produced, but the use of the x variable is actually in a function not included in your post which has the misleading name of `core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once` in the ASM output, but has the much more mangled name of `@_ZN4core3ops8function6FnOnce9call_once17hefa1aa47132c4122E` in the LLVM output of the same playground example.  This is the actual contents of the closure (the `println!("{}", x)`)

```assembly
core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once: # @core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once
# %bb.0:
 # allocate a bunch of stack space for variables and print arguments
 subq   $72, %rsp

 # %edi has the value of x passed in to the closure, which we store in a new stack allocated variable
 movl   %edi, 4(%rsp)

 # we then load the address of that variable into another variable
 leaq   4(%rsp), %rax
 movq   %rax, 8(%rsp)

 # the following is mostly populating the std::fmt::Arguments struct which is passed to print
 movq   core::fmt::num::imp::<impl core::fmt::Display for i32>::fmt@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
 movq   %rax, 16(%rsp)
 leaq   .L__unnamed_2(%rip), %rax
 movq   %rax, 24(%rsp)
 movq   $2, 32(%rsp)
 movq   $0, 40(%rsp)

 # the address of the address of x is loaded into the arguments struct here
 leaq   8(%rsp), %rax
 movq   %rax, 56(%rsp)

 # finish populating the arguments and then call print
 movq   $1, 64(%rsp)
 leaq   24(%rsp), %rdi
 callq  *std::io::stdio::_print@GOTPCREL(%rip)
 addq   $72, %rsp
 retq
```

The playground main function is where the closure is created, but it's not actually called, and like the function above, is mostly populating the complex std::fmt::Arguments struct

```assembly
playground::main: # @playground::main
# %bb.0:
subq    $72, %rsp

 # this creates the closure by storing a pointer to the closure's function
leaq    core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once(%rip), %rax
movl    %eax, 4(%rsp)

 # this stores the closure in main's `x` variable (line 3 of the example)
leaq    4(%rsp), %rax
movq    %rax, 8(%rsp)

 # populate the std::fmt::Arguments struct
movq    core::fmt::num::imp::<impl core::fmt::Display for i32>::fmt@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
movq    %rax, 16(%rsp)
leaq    .L__unnamed_2(%rip), %rax  # the contents of rdx come from .L__unnamed_2(%rip), how to evaluate this part?
movq    %rax, 24(%rsp)  # the contents of rdi come from rax.
movq    $2, 32(%rsp)
movq    $0, 40(%rsp)

 # store the closure (stored in `x`) in the std::fmt::Arguments struct
leaq    8(%rsp), %rax
movq    %rax, 56(%rsp)

 # finish populating and call print
movq    $1, 64(%rsp)
leaq    24(%rsp), %rdi  # rdi should be the register holding the value passed to println!.
callq   *std::io::stdio::_print@GOTPCREL(%rip)
addq    $72, %rsp
retq
```

From the LLVM output, the std::fmt::Arguments is defined as `%"std::fmt::Arguments" = type { [0 x i64], { [0 x { [0 x i8]*, i64 }]*, i64 }, [0 x i64], { i64*, i64 }, [0 x i64], { [0 x { i8*, i64* }]*, i64 }, [0 x i64] }` and I don't understand too many of the internal details, so I'm not sure exactly why it's referencing the the static memory area .L__unnamed_2 but digging into [std::fmt::Arguments](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Arguments.html) might give some more clues

Comment: How does the execution flow is redirected to this "core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once" part? I mean the starting point should be the "main" right? But "core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once" is not part of "main", and I didn't see any callq instruction on it.

Comment: That's right, because there is no call to the closure from main(), as I mentioned.  If you add a call to the closure and compile it, it will generate the call to `core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once` but often it gets optimized into a direct call from main rather than using the closure value itself, since the code in question is fairly simple and the optimizer is fairly aggressive